# EmberJS + TailwindCSS: slow website in production

Tags: ember.js

I'm testing tailwind and ember for a musical website. I experience several bugs:

- in dev server, all links start with a capital letter; on some links the capital letter disappears (live demo, artists). what a strange bug: I thought of correcting it by specifying "uppercase" on all links,
- in production, the navbar doesn't show correctly; it should be like the first template of the webpage (the free template, https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/sections/heroes),
- the speed in production is not good. with vue and Django, I get a lighthouse mobile speed score between 100 and 97. with EmberJS, I get a mobile speed of 70, and a desktop speed of 90 (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fthemusicstop.netlify.app%2F&tab=desktop)

Any help deeply appreciated. I want to use EmberJS instead of Django or Vue but I'm a bit concerned with all the bugs I face.

**Edit: the only question I want to ask is the following**: Why is Emberjs slower than VueJS and Django in production? Here is my source code: https://github.com/nsursock/musicstop

- Mobile lighthouse score: 65
- Desktop lighthouse score: 85

It seems vendor.js' size could be cut in half!

Comment: Hello Nicolas S. Please create one question per issue. Please include all the code needed to understand and reproduce your issue in that question. E.g. for the navbar issue affecting production only we would need to know how you integrated Tailwind into Ember's build pipeline. If you are using PostCSS. If it only runs for production builds or also in development. And the code of the navbar component as well how it is invoked would be very helpful.

Comment: also consider to checkout the official ember community discord channel where you could find help.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your Lighthouse report I'd suggest the following.

The standard EmberJS build tooling is somewhat dated and does not provide the latest and greatest techniques out of the box. There's some history around this which I won't get into but TLDR is that techniques like tree shaking, dead code elimination and route splitting are not done (or at least not to the level you can achieve in 2021 if you configure tools like Webpack yourself).

Depending on the complexity of your application, I would suggest checking out:

- Embroider https://github.com/embroider-build/embroider
- Embroider Realworld Fastboot (a demo app) https://github.com/xg-wang/ember-realworld-fastboot

Using Embroider is still pretty cutting edge so it will probably come with some issues and quirks but its definitely worth checking out/trying.